# How to test a factory function in Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

For a given factory function:

```
export function stringManipulator() {
  const str = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

  return {
    slice: (chars) => str.slice(chars),
    split: (separator) => str.split(separator)
  }
}
```

and a consumer function

```
export function functionToBeTested() {
  const manipulator = stringManipulator();

  return {
    getWord: (wordNum) => manipulator.split(' ')[wordNum]
  }
}
```

I want to create a test for **functionToBeTested** in which I can expect that the **split** method from **stringManipulator** has been called with `' '`

I could use `jest.mock()` for the whole module but I cannot have reference to the internal functions.

Comment: Why not just test the overall outcome, and treat the use of stringManipulator as an implementation detail?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because I want to isolate the tests. These could be exported functions in different files.

Comment: So you want to test the *consumer* of the factory function in isolation? Have you tried replacing the factory with a test double?

Comment: I am not aware of _test double_ , do you mean `jest.mock()` ? If so, how could I spy on the split function?

Comment: You don't need to spy on it. If you mock out stringManipulator then you can make it return exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot get a reference to the factory function from `jest.mock()`
I can change the import expression of the file so that I can spy on all it's exported functions.

```
import * as manipulatorFile;

describe('Test Suite', () => {
  let splitSpy;
  beforeEach(() => {
    splitSpy = jest.fn();
    jest.spyOn(manipulatorFile, 'stringManipulator').mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        split: splitSpy
      }});
  });

  it(' when calling getWordm it should call split with whitespace', () => {
    functionToBeTested().getWord(3);
    expect(splitSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(' ');
  });
});
```